# CDI - ApplicationScoped but configured

Tags: java, configuration, scope, cdi, code-injection

**Problem**

Using CDI I want to produce `@ApplicationScoped` beans.

Additionally I want to provide a configuration annotation to the injection points, e.g.:

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Configuration {

  String value();

}
```

I do not want to write a separate producer for each different possibility of `value`.

---

**Approach**

The usual way would be to make a producer and handle the injection point annotations:

```
@Produces
public Object create(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
    Configuration annotation = injectionPoint.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(Configuration .class);
    ...
}
```

By consequence the bean cannot be application scoped anymore, because each injection point could be possibly different (parameter injectionpoint for producers does not work for `@AplicationScoped`annotated producers).

So this solution does not work.

---

**Question**

I would need a possibility that the injection points with the same value get the same bean instance.

Is there an inbuilt CDI way? Or do I need to somehow "remember" the beans myself in a list, e.g. in the class containing the producer?

What I need is basically an `ApplicationScoped`instance for each different `value`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you try to achieve is not an out fo the box feature in CDI, but thanks to its SPI and a portable extension you can achieve what you need.

This extension will analyse all injection poins with a given type, get the `@Configuration` annotations on each of them and will create a bean in applicationScoped for each different value of the member `value()` in the annotation.

As you'll register multiple beans with the same type you'll have first to transform your annotation into a qualifier

```
@Qualifier
@Target({TYPE, METHOD, PARAMETER, FIELD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Configuration {
    String value();
}
```

Below the class to use to create your bean instances:

```
@Vetoed
public class ConfiguredService {

    private String value;

    protected ConfiguredService() {
    }

    public ConfiguredService(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Note the `@Vetoed` annotation to make sure that CDI won't pick up this class to create a bean as we'll do it ourself. This class has to have a default constructor with no parameter to be used as class of a passivating bean (in application scoped)

Then you need to declare the class of your custom bean. Sees it as a factory and metadata holder (scope, qualifiers, etc...) of your bean.

```
public class ConfiguredServiceBean implements Bean<ConfiguredService>, PassivationCapable {


    static Set<Type> types;
    private final Configuration configuration;
    private final Set<Annotation> qualifiers = new HashSet<>();

    public ConfiguredServiceBean(Configuration configuration) {
        this.configuration = configuration;
        qualifiers.add(configuration);
        qualifiers.add(new AnnotationLiteral<Any>() {
        });
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getBeanClass() {
        return ConfiguredService.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<InjectionPoint> getInjectionPoints() {
        return Collections.EMPTY_SET;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNullable() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Type> getTypes() {
        return types;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Annotation> getQualifiers() {
        return qualifiers;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<? extends Annotation> getScope() {
        return ApplicationScoped.class;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<? extends Annotation>> getStereotypes() {
        return Collections.EMPTY_SET;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAlternative() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public ConfiguredService create(CreationalContext<ConfiguredService> creationalContext) {
        return new ConfiguredService(configuration.value());
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy(ConfiguredService instance, CreationalContext<ConfiguredService> creationalContext) {
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return getClass().toString() + configuration.value();
    }
}
```

Note that the qualifier is the only parameter, allowing us to link the content of the qualifier to the instance in the `create()` method.

Finally, you'll create the extension that will register your beans from a collection of injection points.

```
public class ConfigurationExtension implements Extension {


    private Set<Configuration> configurations = new HashSet<>();

    public void retrieveTypes(@Observes ProcessInjectionPoint<?, ConfiguredService> pip, BeanManager bm) {
        InjectionPoint ip = pip.getInjectionPoint();

        if (ip.getAnnotated().isAnnotationPresent(Configuration.class))
            configurations.add(ip.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(Configuration.class));
        else
            pip.addDefinitionError(new IllegalStateException("Service should be configured"));
    }


    public void createBeans(@Observes AfterBeanDiscovery abd, BeanManager bm) {

        ConfiguredServiceBean.types = bm.createAnnotatedType(ConfiguredService.class).getTypeClosure();

        for (Configuration configuration : configurations) {
            abd.addBean(new ConfiguredServiceBean(configuration));
        }
    }
}
```

This extension is activated by adding its fully qualified classname to the `META-INF/services/javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Extension` text file.

There are other way to create your feature with an extension, but I tried to give you a code working from CDI 1.0 (except for the `@Vetoed` annotation).

You can find the source code of this extension in my [CDI Sandbox on Github](https://github.com/antoinesd/CDI-Sandbox/tree/1c985dde9bb7efcbce5125c2089b8767454dcedd/configured-bean).

The code is quite straight forward, but don't hesitate if you have questions.