# CDI - Dependent & Application Scoped

Tags: java, scope, cdi

#### Situation

I need to Inject a `SessionFactory`.

The challenge is that the factory is different for different environments.
The factory should be `@ApplicationScoped` for each environment.

As it is not known in advance which environments are existing in advance, I created a qualifier using a `@Nonbinding` attribute:

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
public @interface Environment {

  /**
   * Environment identifier
   */
  @Nonbinding String value() default "";

}
```

And a producer:

```
@Produces
@Dependent
@Environment
public SqlSessionFactory produceEnvironmentFactory(InjectionPoint ip)
  throws Exception {
  Environment environment = ip.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(Environment.class);
  return produceFactory(environment.value());
}
```

#### Question

As I need to use the injection point to determine which factory to produce, I am not able to use the `@ApplicationScoped` annotation.

Is there an easy way to do what I want using CDI?
Or do I need to implement a mechanism myself (using a map or similar)?

#### Edit:

The environments are not going to be dev, test, staging, prod or similar. It is possible that multiple environments coexist.

Comment: I didn't use that myself yet but if I understand it correctly the value should just be binding and you should get an application scoped instance per environment. Besides that, do you have different environments in the same JVM instance or is it something like dev, test, prod, i.e. there's only one active environment in a JVM?

Comment: If I'm wrong (and I'm not sure I'm not) maybe this would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36065091/cdi-applicationscoped-but-configured

Comment: Thomas has a point with environments, you have to explain how the env. work/cooperate/co-exist in your app. If there is only one at a time, you should be fine with just `@ApplicationScoped` producer. Also I think you should be able to use `InjectionPoint` along with `@ApplicationScoped` but I would have to test that.

Comment: I updated the question and added the information. @Thomas: if the value is binding I will have to provide a producer for each possible environment and thats exactly what I cant do, as it is not known what environments exist.

Comment: Just realized that the link I posted was your question as well. Didn't that help here? Thinking some more about it, CDI might actually not be able to handle your case by itself so maintaining a map in your producer (which should itself be application scoped) might be one of the more viable options.

Comment: Is it maybe a *new custom scope* that you need?

Comment: @Thomas: Thank you, did completely forget about that question that should solve this problem!